# How can I create a link to a users 365 profile in SharePoint 2013

Tags: office-365

I want a link to go to a users SharePoint on a corporate 365 account.

so for example:

John Doe  <------ link would go to John Does "About Me" in Microsoft 365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url format for My Sites is:

```
https://<tenant>-my.sharepoint.com/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=<account name>
```

Account name follows the following format:

```
i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7C<user>%40<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com
```

Which, when decoded, looks like:

```
i:0#.f|membership|user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

As per your comment, person@company.com's user profile will be at:

```
https://company-my.sharepoint.com/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cperson%40company.com
```

Comment: Whoa that's amazing. So could you give me an example if this is the information?
company-my.sharepoint.com  user is person@company.com

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That's everything I wanted and more! You're amazing!